# Optional Parameters in **kwargs

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, python-2.7, cx-oracle

I am not able to handle to pass optional parameters in python `**kwargs`

```
def ExecuteyourQuery(self, queryStatement, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.cursorOBJ is not None:
        resultOBJ = self.cursorOBJ.execute(queryStatement, *args,**kwargs)
    self.resultsVal = resultOBJ.fetchall()
```

---

The below statement works fine when I am calling the function

```
ExecuteyourQuery('select * from item_table where x = :x and y:y', x, y)
```

But when I give an extra argument which is not mentioned in the query, like

```
ExecuteyourQuery('select * from item_table where x = :x and y:y', x, y, z)
```

It returns 0 as output

Comment: I am little unsure about the query that you make? Is the condition with "y" as intended?

Comment: What do you mean with "the below statement works fine..."? What does it returns when no passing z? And as mentioned above, is the "and" condition with 'y' as intended (and y:y)?

Answer (score 2):

When using args as the last parameter of your function, you can pass any number of **arguments** after the formal arguments, when existing. Args is a [tuple](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm).

```
def my_method(farg, *args):
  print('FARG: ', farg)
  print('ARGS: ', args)

my_method('Formal Argument', 1, 2, 3)
```

When using kwargs as the last parameter of your function, you can pass any number of **named arguments** after the formal arguments, when existing. Kwargs is a [dictionary](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm).

```
def my_method(farg, **kwargs):
  print('FARG: ', farg)
  print('KWARGS: ', kwargs)

my_method('Formal Argument', kwarg_1 = 1, kwarg_2 = 2, kwarg_3 = 3)
```

When using both args and kwargs as the last parameteres of your function, you can pass any number of **arguments** (that will be mapped to args) and **named arguments** (that will be mapped to kwargs) after the formal arguments, when existing.

```
def my_method(farg, *args, **kwargs):
  print('FARG: ', farg)
  print('ARGS: ', args)
  print('KWARGS: ', kwargs)

my_method('Formal Argument', 1, 2, 3, kwarg_1 = 1, kwarg_2 = 2, kwarg_3 = 3)
```

Try this out and see the results in your console, hopefully it will help you solve your original problem :)

Comment: Found a nice to read reference also on [this site][https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/], please, take a look!

Answer (score 0):

another way to do this is by setting a default value for a parameter

```
def method(one, two, three=3):
   print(one)
   print(two)
   if three != 3:  # don't have to use it like this but it is a default value
      print(three)
```

this set a default value if the parameter is not filled
if it is filled it will overrule the default value and use that

```
method(11, 22)  # prints first two parameters
method(23, 54, 89)  # prints all three
```

Not sure if this is what your looking for but it is another way